# Attach pivot table id by array order

Tags: php, laravel

I want store id's by array order

`$item->categories()->attach(request('category_ids'));`

For example:

If `request('category_ids')` equal to: `[4,3,2,1]`

I want store record by order => 4 3 2 1

But it store => 1 2 3 4
[image: store state]

My pivot table:

```
Schema::create('category_item', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->integer('item_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('item_id')->references('id')->on('items')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('restrict');

            $table->primary(['item_id', 'category_id']);

});
```

I open an [issues](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/25161) on laravel.

Comment: Why should it matter what order the database stores records?

Comment: @pseudoanime I want display it with order to my customers. Is there another way?

Comment: what your attach method do?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that's possible.

Comment: @SergeyShuryakov  it's laravel method. that insert id's to pivot table.

Comment: probably `detach(request('category_ids'))` then `attach(request('category_ids'))` can help

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to overwrite attach method, but

> I want display it with order to my customers. Is there another way? – Mr.Json

you may do this:

```
Item::with(['categories' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('category_id', 'desc');
}])->all();
```

After you comment i think you need `sort` column in your `category_item` table:

```
Schema::create('category_item', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->integer('item_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('item_id')->references('id')->on('items')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('sort')->unsigned()->nullable(false);

        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('restrict');

        $table->primary(['item_id', 'category_id']);
```

});

Now, need map yor request, for example:

```
$categoryIds = array_map(function ($categoryId) {
     return ['category_id' => $categoryId, 'sort' => $categoryId];
}, request('category_ids'))
```

And attach:

```
$item->categories()->attach($categoryIds);
```

Comment: Thanks but it work only for `1 2 3 4` , if `6 5 3 9`  not work. i want exactly with array order.

Comment: `$myArr= [4,1,2,3]; $item->categories()->attach($myArr);` This insert record order by 1 2 3 4,  can you fix this example? thanks

Comment: I open an [issues](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/25161) on laravel.